# is it possible to find if someone views page source

Tags: php, javascript

Is it possible to find any information about people who view the source of a web page ? Is it possible to perhaps have a javascript to detect a keystroke entered on your page ?

Comment: Two different issues. You can detect keystrokes, but you cannot detect view-sourcing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to find any information about people who view the source of a web page ?

No

> Is it possible to perhaps have a javascript to detect a keystroke entered on your page ?

Yes (the `keydown`, `keyup` and `keypress` events), but there are numerous ways to view the source and the DOM without using the keyboard.